# Use VBA to create a dynamic table with date values given start date and number of weeks

Tags: excel, vba

I've been trying to determine how to dynamically scale out an excel table using only function logic, and I can't seem to figure it out. I'm starting to think it's only possible using VBA, in which I'm not too familiar.

What I'm trying to do:
I have a start date as well as a duration (in weeks). I have implemented manual logic that can provide me the week ending date for every week, but I'm trying to automate this process.

Available parameters:

Project Start Date: 5/14/2018

Project End Date:   6/29/2018   this field being calculated: "((IF($B$1,$B$1+(B3*7),""))-7*1)+6-WEEKDAY(((IF($B$1,$B$1+(1*7),""))-7*1))"

Total Project Weeks:    7    this field being referenced in above logic

Desired outcome:

Dynamic table that populates end of week dates in different columns using above parameters

"5/18/2018  5/25/2018   6/1/2018    6/8/2018    6/15/2018   6/22/2018   6/29/2018"

Manual logic: 
"=((IF($B$1,$B$1+(1*7),""))-7*1)+6-WEEKDAY(((IF($B$1,$B$1+(1*7),""))-7*1))"

"=((IF($B$1,$B$1+(2*7),""))-7*1)+6-WEEKDAY(((IF($B$1,$B$1+(2*7),""))-7*1))"

"=((IF($B$1,$B$1+(3*7),""))-7*1)+6-WEEKDAY(((IF($B$1,$B$1+(3*7),""))-7*1))"

Thank you for your time.

Comment: It would probably help if you can post some screenshots

Comment: Sure thing, sorry about that, @Absinthe.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/uqqz6iv6yv3cqgj/Excel%20Params%202.PNG?dl=0

https://www.dropbox.com/s/kgabrzk88bq8ley/Excel%20Params%203.PNG?dl=0

https://www.dropbox.com/s/mhqq6j8hlxb3pfg/Excel%20Params.PNG?dl=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on having a start date in B1, end date in B2, and number of weeks in B3; the following VBA code will populate row 1 with week end dates starting in D1 and moving right:

```
Sub headers()
    Dim start As Double
    Dim weeks As Integer

    start = Range("B1").Value
    weeks = Range("B3").Value
    For i = 0 To weeks - 1
        Cells(1, 4 + i).Value = start + 4 + (i * 7)
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks @DavidP, this is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: if I wanted to take this a step further and return only the date of the Friday in each week, how would I go about that?

Comment: @WillCrayger I'm not sure what you're asking, this returns the date of the Friday in each week as values in the first row.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this array formula

```
=IF(COLUMN(A1:Z1)>A2,"",A1+7-WEEKDAY(A1,16)+(COLUMN(A1:Z1)-COLUMN(A1))*7)
```

If you highlight a range big enough to hold the maximum number of weeks (say A3:Z3), then enter it as an array formula.

A1 contains the start date and A2 the number of weeks.